# How to query against multiple child elements using contains similarly to SQL's IN statement

Tags: linq

I have a repository method that gets all the Users from the database. Each User has a single child object called Profile and one or many child objects that fall under a List called Companies. This repository method has been tested, works fine and returns type IQueryable, which I am using as a base to later get narrowed down results once a query is triggered.

What I am trying to do is get a list of users from that repository method that have at least one associated company that has an ID that matches an element in an existing list called 'targetCompanyIDs'. The list is of type List<int> and the company's ID is also an int. Here is my attempt to generate that list of users:

```
List<User> usersData = rep.GetUsersProfilesAndCompanies().Where(u => targetCompanyIDs.Contains(u.CompanyStructures.ID)).ToList();
```

The error I get is that type List does not contain a definition for ID. Makes sense, right? So what I tried to do is treat the User's associated companies as some type of group or aggregate. Here is my second attempt:

```
List<User> usersData = rep.GetUsersProfilesAndCompanies().Where(u => targetCompanyIDs.Contains(u.CompanyStructures.Any(cs => cs.ID))).ToList();
```

What I am trying to say is, for any company the user has associated with it, does that company's ID match with the list targetCompanyIDs? If so, include the user on the list. Unfortunately this gives an 'invalid argument' error.

Is there any way in LINQ to query against multiple child elements like I am trying to do here?

Comment: Can you please give us some example code? For one, it is not really clear what `GetUsersProfilesAndCompanies` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way :

```
List<User> usersData = rep.GetUsersProfilesAndCompanies()
                          .Where(u => u.CompanyStructures.Any(o => targetCompanyIDs.Contains(o.ID)))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: This looked like the correct syntax for what I was trying to do in my second code example, BUT, I am getting a compiler error with this code: "the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Any<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' has some invalid arguments". There was an interesting comment left yesterday that is now deleted about abandoning the repository method and writing a new one for this particular problem. In light of how complex this LINQ statement is getting, I think I will give up on code re-use for simplicity's sake.